# how to change the date format from mm/dd/yyyy to dd-mm-yyyy in combobox?

Tags: c#, .net, date, format

i have a combobox which is displaying date from database...in my database the date enteries are in the format of mm/dd/yyyy but i want to display them in the format of     dd-mm-yyyy...in that combobox..when the application run.

Comment: You say "in my database..." - well, in the database they are *typically* just an integer  (they don't have an implicit string format). Also, it **really** matters how you are handing the values to the combobox. Are you giving it strings? DateTimes? Are you using databinding? And if so, to what? A DataTable? A class? It really matters. Can you please add more detail, preferably some code that shows you setting up the combobox?

Comment: i have used used data adapter and data set and sent the values to table using data source...
so my combobox is displaying the dates in the format of mm/dd/yyyy because in my database it was in that format...but i need to change the format in the front end before loading values in the combo..and i need to change the format from mm/dd/yyyy to dd-mm-yyyy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either convert the format of your date before you load them to the combo box or run this code after the combobox have been filled:

```
for (int index = 0; index < this.comboBox1.Items.Count; index++)
        {
            this.comboBox1.Items[index] = DateTime.Parse(this.comboBox1.Items[index].ToString()).ToString("dd-mm-yyyy");
        }
```

Edited:

If your are using databinding and sure that the type of data being displayed is date. Try this:

```
 this.comboBox1.FormatString = "dd-MM-yyyy";
```

Comment: You can also use the FormatString property to control the format of the items. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.formatstring.aspx. This page has a link to a more detailed subject about formatting.

Comment: thanks for ur reply...can u tell me what is the procedure to convert the format for date when the values are populated in combobox using dataadapter...
how could i convert the format before the dates are populated in the combobox..

Comment: @zoya - please check if the second code works for you. Thanks!

Comment: im using data adapter and with the help of data set im entering the values in the table..and what do u mean by databing??

Comment: @zoya - oh its databinding sorry I mispelled it. are you looping the dataset's datatable - rows that contains the date and adds them 1 by 1? Please paste your code so I can find a way to fix it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you can accept to have a global change in the app, set the CultureInfo.CurrentCulture to a European locale.

Comment: yes - or change the machine's regional and language settings.

Comment: i appriciate the answers and replies but dnt know how to accept them

Comment: thanks..
now can u help me to sort out my current problem..
im populating the dates in the combobox using data adapter and i want to convert the date format before loading the dates in the combobox..in c#.net ..is there any easy way out??

Comment: Add a column to your data table and use the code like in the answer above to populate that column in the format you like. Then bind your combo box to this new column instead of the original one.